# How to Convert String to array in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Actually, I'm making a day wise items like (item name,description,price) like this but now coming same line all the data like (Hot & Crisp - ItemChicken Snacker,description,$8-$5) i want like below that format.

```
name:"Hot & Crisp
description:
price:"$6"

name":"Chicken Snacker"
description":"A delicious chunk of chicken served in a soft sesame bun, with salad and Thousand Island sauce."
price:"$5"
```

BUT now my output is like this:**(name:Hot & Crisp - ItemChicken Snacker,description:jjjdjdjdjdj,price:$8-$5)**
Mycode:

```
var ItemsDetails = v.itemsArray;
var ItemsName = JSON.stringify(ItemsDetails);
                                lg(ItemsName);
                                var myObject = eval('(' + ItemsName + ')');
                                for (i in myObject)
                                {
                                    var itemname = myObject[i]["name"];
                                    html += '<b>'+ itemname +'</b>';
                                }
```

Comment: I can't figure out what your question is. Please tell me what your input is to get to your desired output. Also, I think your jQuery tag is redundant and you should add the JavaScript tag.

Comment: what is this `lg(ItemsName);` do, and why have you stringified the array if you want to iterate over it?

Comment: Jay try to clearly mention your problem, otherwise it becomes difficult to give a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit this line:

```
html += '<b>'+ itemname +'</b>';
```

to:

```
html += '<b>'+ itemname +'</b><br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

not really sure, but this may be similar to what you are looking for.

```js
var ItemsDetails = [{
  name: "Hot & Crisp",
  description: "",
  price: "$6"
}, {
  name: "Chicken Snacker",
  description: "A delicious chunk of chicken served in a soft sesame bun, with salad and Thousand Island sauce.",
  price: "$5"
}];
//var ItemsName = JSON.stringify(ItemsDetails);

//var myObject = eval('(' + ItemsName + ')');
//for (i in myObject)
//{
//    var itemname = myObject[i]["name"];
//    html += '<b>'+ itemname +'</b>';
//}
var htmlOut = "";
for (var i = 0; i < ItemsDetails.length; i++) {
  htmlOut += '<p>';
  htmlOut += 'Name: ' + ItemsDetails[i].name + '<br>';
  htmlOut += 'Description: ' + ItemsDetails[i].description + '<br>';
  htmlOut += 'Price: ' + ItemsDetails[i].price;
  htmlOut += '</p>';
}

document.getElementById("sampleDiv").innerHTML = htmlOut;
```

```html
<div id="sampleDiv"></div>
```